# cordova-plugin-ionic-webview @ 2.x vs @1.2.1

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, phaser-framework, ionic-webview

We are currently using the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview to enable WKWebView in our phaser app for iOS/Android (I know that cordova-plugin-ionic-webview only serves iOS).

I recently saw the plugin cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@beta i.e. Ionic Web View cordova-plugin-ionic-webview @ 2.x Beta.

My main questions would be:

1. What improvement does it bring over the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1
2. I am a little confused whether it works for Android also
3. Is there any other plugin which could be more suitable for me?
4. After adding this plugin, on iPhone X, the bottom Home Indicator overlaps my app's footer. Any workaround for this since we have a canvas based Phaser framework app and its difficult to use safe area insets.

Tried pasting
- (UIRectEdge)preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures{
    return UIRectEdgeAll;
};
in CDVViewController but still doesnt work.

Comment: Anyone checking this post, please check the changelog of `ionic-webview` https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-2018-07-23

Comment: @Gabe you can change the hostname https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/blob/master/README.md#hostname

Comment: @PeterHaddad I already did that, the problem is that the ODR resources are located outside the www folder so they can only be accessed using cdvfile:// and the ionic-webview blocks these